# How can I do string substitution in a variable created using cat in a Makefile?

Tags: make

In my `Makefile`, I'm assigning some variables based on the contents of a file, and I'd like to define a new variable by doing a string replacement on the contents of the file.

I have a file called `.file-a` in my project directory with the following contents:

```
foo-bar
```

And my `Makefile` looks like this:

```
FILE_A_NAME := .file-a
FILE_A_CONTENTS := `cat $(FILE_A_NAME)`
NEW_VAR := $(subst -,_, $(FILE_A_CONTENTS))

.PHONY: foo
foo: 
    @echo $(NEW_VAR)
```

I'd like `make foo` to echo `foo_bar`, but instead, I'm getting:

```
cat: .file_a: No such file or directory
```

It seems like `NEW_VAR` is doing the substitution on `FILE_A_NAME`. How can I get the substitution to work on `FILE_A_CONTENTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `shell` function to run `cat`:

```
FILE_A_CONTENTS := $(shell cat $(FILE_A_NAME))
```